# How to assert when return null

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, code-coverage

I tried to look all over for an answer to this, but all the treads I kept coming across anywhere where all about "X keeps returning null, it's not supposed to" type issues.

My issue is I cannot find anywhere how to system assert when you have "return null" on a function that is supposed to return a type. This is the code I am writing test coverage for:

```
public static Id getRecordTypeId(SObjectType sobjectType,string RecordTypeName) {
    if (CACHE == null) {
        CACHE = new Map<String, Id>();
        for (RecordType rt :  [SELECT Id, SObjectType, DeveloperName FROM RecordType]) 
            CACHE.put(rt.SObjectType + SEPARATOR + rt.DeveloperName, rt.Id);            
    }

    string sKey=String.valueOf(sobjectType) + SEPARATOR + RecordTypeName;
    if (CACHE.containsKey(sKey))    
        return CACHE.get(sKey);
    else{
        throw new VSException('Invalid Record Type: ' + RecordTypeName);  
        return null;   //how do I get test coverage on this one line?
    }
}
```

I did not write it, I'm just writing the coverage for it. I have literally covered every single piece of the code except for the "return null" at the end. I cannot figure it out. Below is my test code:

```
Test.startTest();
    //getRecordTypeID test
    String rtString = ObjectUtils.getRecordTypeId (Account.SObjectType, 'Customer');
    String erString;

    //this below line just throws and error and ends the test if I try it this way.
    //erString = ObjectUtils.getRecordTypeId (Account.SObjectType, 'VSExceptionTest0001');

    Boolean eTest = false;

    Try
    {
        erString = ObjectUtils.getRecordTypeId (Account.SObjectType, 'VSExceptionTest0001');
    }
    Catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.debug('Exception :: ' + e);
        eTest = true;
        System.assertEquals(null, erString); //does not work for asserting return null
    }

Test.stopTest();
```

The test itself is passing each time, it just refuses to give me the last bit of coverage. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly recommend you never put assertions in a `try`/`catch`/`finally` block. Ever. You also shouldn't put them in `if`/`else` blocks.

Here is a strategy I prefer for testing that an `Exception` should/shouldn't be thrown.

```
static testMethod void testThrow()
{
    // setup

    Exception expectedException;
    Test.startTest();
        try
        {
            // some operation that should throw
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            expectedException = e;
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException, '<message>');
}
static testMethod void testHappyPath()
{
    // setup

    Exception unexpectedException;
    Test.startTest();
        try
        {
            // some operation that should not throw
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            unexpectedException = e;
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(null, unexpectedException, '<message>');
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I didn't originally have it in there because I've had it mentioned before it's bad practice, but I got frustrated when I couldn't figure it out, and didn't know what else to try. Testing for the exception itself should cover the "return null" then?

Comment: @Genko It's actually *impossible* to hit that `return null;` line. I didn't notice it at first but the `throw` halts execution.

Comment: So then is this a situation then were I will probably never have 100% test coverage on this code, because I cannot cover that line? It's okay if so, I just need to know if that's the case so I can stop trying to hit it.

Comment: Just remove that line. It adds nothing. No you can't hit it.

Comment: I will do that then~ Thank you for also explaining asserting error messages. I needed that as well for what I'm working on. Appreciate it!